# Is there any way to determine whether a user clicked Print or Cancel in WebBrowser.ShowDialog()?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, webbrowser-control

I'm just trying to determine if the user selected Print or Cancel from the dialog. I can't find any event or property that might let me know whether or not the document displayed in the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control was actually sent to the printer. The closest I can get right now is determining whether the dialog opened.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

(We're using DevEx, so if what I'm after is possible through one of their controls, I'd be interested in that, as well.)

Background: What we're showing in the WebBrowser are the contents of xml files sitting in a directory next to their XSL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about `ShowPrintDialog()` I think there's a problem in having a return type since it calls the UI of the selected printer.
This UI is not necessarily standardized so that you may have a window with no cancel button :/

When facing a similar problem I just created a simple "Print Form" and for printing used `WebBrowser.Print()`